# Why does the web browser display a time stamp under an image that I'm displaying in html?

Tags: html

My problem: I'm writing the code for a website that calls up an image, but when the image shows up the web browser displays a time stamp that is displayed under the image I call up.
My question: I would like to know why is a time stamp being displayed under the image I call up?

Here is my code:

```
<center><img src = "pirate flag.jpg" height = "150", width = "70"/><center>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESSEz.png)

Comment: Please add (many) more details to your question to clarify the exact issue

Comment: No code = can't help. :\

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question and see [ask]

Comment: What are you asking dude?  I can't make heads or tails of what your problem is.  And even if you gave a detailed description of your problem, I still would not be able to help you because you put no code in your post.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have additional code underneath this line of Html which instructs the browser to display the time or the image needs to be altered in a image editor to remove the date.

Use the following code to display the image without time stamp:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<center><img src = "pirate flag.jpg" height = "150", width = "70"/><center>
</body>
</html>
```